# Transfer events from one CloudWatch log stream to another

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

After creating a log stream **old_stream**, I realized that it is in incorrect log group. I have created another log group and a stream **new_stream** within it. Now, I want to transfer all the events from my **old_stream** to **new_stream**. How do I do that?

I tried using AWS CLI, [get-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-log-events.html) gave me all the log events in **old_stream**. I got the result into a local file, updated it in correct format and used [put-log-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/put-log-events.html) to put them into **new_stream**.

However, I got following error: **The batch of log events in a single PutLogEvents request cannot span more than 24 hours**.

I have log events spanning more than 1 day.

Is there a better way to do this?